# UIView over another uiview and pass touches through

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view sitting over another view. The top view has a UITapGestureRecognizer so I can close the menus (click outside of the menus). But the layer below this needs to receive all the touches.

I can get single finger gestures to pass through, but I can't get the pinch gesture to pass through.

Comment: Make sure that multiple touches are enabled in both views.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a situation where you don't necessarily know the order or amount of layers underneath the top that need to receive actions? Based on a little research it sounds like lots of people have encountered this problem with pinch to zoom... you might have to come up with some other solution/work-around. I'm guessing there is something unique about 2 finger gestures that prevents them from being passed through the view hierarchy. Could be a technical limitation or a bug.

Comment: Multi touch wasn't enabled thanks. Too many late nights.

Comment: @MSgambel: Add that as an answer, so smcdrc can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that multiple touches are enabled in both views. That way, a pinch can be recognized! Hope that helps!